# Creating unlimited instagram accounts using python

Tags: python, gmail, bots, instagram

I am working on a program that allows me to create unlimited Instagram accounts but first I need to create multiple emails. I am currently using google mail (Gmail) and I got stuck on the username part. I am planning to let me program type random words in the first and last name box and for the username to press the usernames Gmail offers to me. But selenium don't have a function for selecting those usernames because they always change.

[image: google username box]

The jsname for the usernames suggestion doesn't change so I wanted to use selenium to find element by that but selenium doesn't offer `find_element_by_jsname`.

Can any one help me on how to select that?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty curious to know the purpose of this script.

Apart from that, what I would suggest is maybe selecting the class of the "li" (list item) and go from there. I've noticed that the other suggestion that Google gave you for username has the same class and I believe you don't really care which suggestion you are going to pick, as long as you can create an account, right? As long as I remember, Selenium had a find_item_by_class option or something similar, It has been quite some time since my last web scraping scripts.

Comment: Hi Stefan, so I want to create multiple Instagram accounts but I don't want to come up with say 1000 usernames. So I wanted to input some letters in the username box and just click the usernames that is available on Instagram (what Instagram provided). Because if I manually come up with usernames, then some of the usernames that I come up with might not work because Instagram already have them. So that's why I think it would be easier to just use the usernames that Instagram provided.